# Why does Windows only allow one application to access the webcam?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, video, webcam

I've been trying to make a sample webcam app in c#, and I discovered the app cannot run at the same time Skype or Oovoo or any other application is running? (and vice versa) Why do applications get exclusive locks over a webc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Video capture APIs come from time when adding layers to share video hardware was unreasonable in terms of performance. Also, with 2+ apps working with a camera one would have to make them agree on capture format in some way that both are satisfied. So it was made the simplest and straightforward way: you grabbed the camera, it's yours and you can set it up for your own needs. However others would wait for you to release the hardware before anyone else can use it.

You can find third party software that shares a camera, which internally grabs it exclusively and then exposes virtual camera that is shareable. This trades off performance for flexibility.

Audio APIs were also locking hardware exclusively some time ago, but then at some point OS APIs introduced hardware abstraction layers to share hardware and do mixing from multiple applications behind the scene.

Comment: Is there any hack that bypasses this limitation? Or is it 120% impossible. :( The only things I can find are SplitCam and ManyCam which are absolutely terrible.

Comment: No hack, it is behavior by design. Your best move is to find a camera virtualization/sharing software which is "less terrible".

Comment: Thanks for your help though. :) How hard would it be to create the virtualiztion software myself? All I need is a no fluff completely minimal application that can capture the stream and output it to another "device" for skype/oovoo to use.

Comment: There has been a number of attempts to do it, see discussions http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pushsource+vcam and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/windows/desktop?query=virtual%20share%20camera&rq=meta:Search.MSForums.ForumID%28e17d4690-29b7-46c1-b2a2-34394bf59032%29+site:microsoft.com&rn=DirectShow+Development+Forum&ac=8 Among other those result in terrible cam splitters you already discovered. Honestly, I am not aware if there is a decent one among splitters available out there. You can certanly make a try to make your own too, it is doable.

Answer (score -9):

This is probably intended to avoid an application spying on people while they are using their webcam through skype or whatever.

Comment: Any proof or information to back that up? Otherwise it's just conjecture and not an "expert answer".

Comment: "This is probably" is not the start of an actual fact..

Comment: I agree that a "guess" is probably not the best answer, but in this case it is not too far off to assume security _could_ be an issue. Also, since when only "expert answers" are allowed here?

Comment: This is a good supposition, however think of the following: video capture API existed in this shape 15 years ago where bandwidth of networks was insufficient to stream, cameras were rare and high end hardware, and active capture (esp. with real time compression) alone would load the host in a way that silent spying is just impossible.

Comment: It has nothing to do with security, it is everything to do with the limitations of the hardware and device drivers. Making devices capable of doing this would be expensive in terms of hardware and harder for the software and drivers all for hardly any demand.