# Two Instances from one Webcam

Tags: c#, winapi, video, directshow, directshow.net

I am new at DirectShow and found one [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markhsch/archive/2007/11/19/c-webcam-user-control-source.aspx) to capture when i ran two instances of this app it throws exceptions like camera is already in use.I having a requirement that the same camera will be shared by two Applications.

Is it possible to acheive this using any filters

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectShow web cameras are typically exclusive use resources, applications cannot share them. One solution is to use a virtual camera software that creates a virtual device available to many apps, backed by real devices. Or, you can also implement the sharing yourself.

See also:

- [Why does Windows only allow one application to access the webcam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339778/why-does-windows-only-allow-one-application-to-access-the-webcam)
- [Is there a way to create a duplicate device of webcam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190503/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-duplicate-device-of-webcam/25191094#25191094)