# AForge: How to open a Video Capture Device in Multiple Windows (i.e Main/Live Windows, and Preview Window at same time)

Tags: wpf, directshow, video-capture, aforge

I am using AForge.Video.DirectShow for displaying from multiple cameras (in image controls) on Main Window. Now as a part of camera selection, I am displaying a separate window as dialog with preview.

The preview is able to show video from capture devices. But if the capture device is already opened in main window, nothing is getting displayed in this preview window.

So the main question is how to display video from same capture device on multiple windows i.e main window, preview window. I will be thankful if i get directions and approach to solve this.

I am using c# wpf, and AForge V2.2.5

Answer (score 1):

Respective DirectShow filter which streams video from camera can participate in one active filter graph at a time. Hence, you cannot have the camera streaming in two or more sessions running simultaneously.

You typically want to implement teeing of the video feed yourself.

See also:

- [Two Instances from one Webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28690521/868014)